# PowerBi Line Chart with Field Parameters

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, linechart

I have a problem that I couldn't figure it out. I have created a line chart to put the data in it but I wanted to create a slicer to choose what columns to put whenever I want however. The slicer works perfectly well with the table but not with the line chart the data just don't show [image]

Here is another image after the I noticed that I didn't show that I put the parameters in Y axis.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

as you can see here I put the parameters but they are not working or showing any data
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP1kw.png

Comment: Shouldn't you drop the Parameter in the `Y axis` rather than in `Legeng`?

Comment: I am not showing it but I did , and the parameter was not working nothing appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a parameter to display values not attributes, so you can not use implicit measures here.

You first have to create all explicit measures you want to offer in the parameter.

For example : `Total Upg Target = SUM(Table[Upg Target])` etc.

Then you can use these measures as your parameter's fields, which can then be used to compute values in your charts.